# Interaction between Browser, Application, IdentityServer and ADFS during Authentication

Tags: adfs, identityserver3, federated-identity, ws-federation, identityserver4

I would like to check my understanding of the authentication interaction between a Browser, an Application, IdentityServer and ADFS 3.0 for a federated authentication scenario.

I created the sequence diagram below after some googling and reviewing logs in Identity Server.

It seems straightforward up to step 7, but I believe I may be missing or confusing the interaction that takes place after that between IdentityServer and ADFS 3.0. For example, I can see an IdentityServer log entry that states:

*Callback invoked from external identity provider*

This line would seem to imply direct interaction between ADFS and IdentityServer and contradict step #9 in my diagram. So, does the browser forward the ADFS token to IdentityServer as in step #9 in my diagram, or does ADFS send the token directly to IdentityServer? If the later, where would that occur in the sequence.

Any insight would be very much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Everything is done with redirects.

Comment: The only use case where there is server to server AFAIK is when you use artifact resolution in SAML where a back channel is invoked.